# How to get a string array out of a string stream which gets generated as an intermediary result?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have this below code:

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String,  String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("colors", "Red, Green, Blue, Purple");

        map.entrySet()
           .stream()
           .filter(entrySet -> entrySet.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("Colors"))
           .map(entrySet -> entrySet.getValue().replaceAll(" ", "").split(","));
    }
}
```

As you can see I am looking for a specific entry in the map and then extracting the value associated with that entry. The value is a String (i.e. `Red, Green, Blue, Purple`) and I require these comma-delimited colors as a String array. Also, I am removing any white space before splitting this String. Using Streams I was able to get this `Stream<String[]>` from the above code.

But ultimately I need a String array that contains these colors so can anyone tell me how I can collect a String array from this `Stream<String[]>`?

And I want to use just streams, no `for` loop or enhanced `for` loop.

Comment: If you are “looking for a specific entry in the map”, you should just use `get` instead of a linear search through the entire map, e.g. `String[] result = map.get("colors").split(", ");` If inconsistent use of uppercase and lowercase really is a requirement for your software, you can simply use a `TreeMap` instead of a `HashMap`. Then, `get("Colors")` will also work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

map.put("colors", "Red, Green, Blue, Purple");
map.put("numbers", "One, Two, Three");
map.put("COLORS", "Yellow, Magenta, Cyan");

String[] result = map.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("Colors"))
    .map(entry -> entry.getValue().replaceAll(" ", "").split(","))
    .flatMap(Stream::of)
    .toArray(String[]::new);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

output:

```
[Yellow, Magenta, Cyan, Red, Green, Blue, Purple]
```

if you only want the first match

```
String[] result = map.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("Colors"))
    .map(entry -> entry.getValue().replaceAll(" ", "").split(","))
    .findFirst().orElse(new String[0]);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

output:

```
[Yellow, Magenta, Cyan]
```

Comment: you can also use ```Stream::of ```

Comment: Thank you, folks, for your quick reply. I now got the desired result. Just one thing I want clarity on i.e. in this below line of code: "toArray(String[]::new);". I see that this could be replaced with a lambda expression inside toArray() i.e. toArray(size->new String[size]); and this lambda has a target type of IntFunction but the thing which confuses me is, does this "size" parameter gets its value automatically based on our string stream coming from flatMap()?

Comment: Also this code: String[] result = map.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("Colors"))
    .map(entry -> entry.getValue().replaceAll(" ", "").split(","))
    .findFirst().orElse(new String[0]); is giving compiler error. Can you explain the last part of this code( .findFirst().orElse(new String[0]);)?

Comment: @Shri `.findFirst()` returns the current first element of the stream. However, if the stream is empty at that point, it returns the value specified by `.orElse()`.

Comment: More direct with `split("\\s*,\\s*")`

Comment: @g00se Leading or trailing whitespaces will give different results.

Comment: @英語は苦手 sorry, I meant `.trim().split("\\s*,\\s*"))`. The delimiter is `,` so that approach would preserve, e.g. `"green , dark brown, blue"`

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8 - [`Pattern.splitAsStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#splitAsStream(java.lang.CharSequence))

You can split a `String` on *non-alphabetic* characters by using regular expression `"^\\p{Alpha}+"` (*captures one or more non-alphabetic character*) and Java 8 method `Pattern.splitAsStream()`. Which generates a Stream of elements identical to the ones produced by `String.split()`. The difference is that `Pattern.splitAsStream()` creates a stream directly from the regex engine **without** allocating an intermediate array in memory (which is an advantage).

*There's one **edge-case**:* the very first element would be an empty string. It could happen, for instance, when there's a leading white space at the beginning of the string. Since we don't need it appear in the result, we can discard it using [`dropWhile()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#dropWhile(java.util.function.Predicate)).

***Note** that the same issue would arise with* `String.split()` *used in another answer, where it's not handled.*

Then to apply the same transformation as in the previous example with one small addition: we need to address the edge-case when the givens string starts with a white-space. In such case, the very first element would be an empty string, and we can use to discard such string.

To avoid recompiling the regex pattern multiple times, it makes sense to store in the static final variable.

```
public static final Pattern NON_ALPHA = Pattern.compile("[^\\p{Alpha}]+");
```

```
Map<String, String> colorsByKey = // initializing the map
    
String[] result = colorsByKey.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("colors"))
    .flatMap(e -> NON_ALPHA.splitAsStream(e.getValue()).dropWhile(String::isEmpty))
    .toArray(String[]::new);
```

#### Note:

In case if colors can contain white-spaces somewhere in the middle, i.e. there could be strings like `"Red, Dark Blue"`, which should result in colors `"Red` and `"DarkBlue"`, you can change the pattern to `"\\s*,\\s*"` (*coma surrounded by optional white spaces*). And `map()` operation should be added to the pipeline to remove the white spaces from the middle of each string before collecting into the array:

```
.map(s -> s.replaceAll("\\s*", ""))
```

## Java 9 - [`Matcher.results()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#results())

Another option is to capture sequences of *alphabetic characters* with a regular expression `"\\p{Alpha}+"` and using Java 9 method `Matcher.results()` generate a `Stream` of `MatchResult`s, which is an object containing information about the matching group of characters.

To extract the matching substring from a `MatchResult` we can use method [`MatchResult.group()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/MatchResult.html#group()).

```
public static final Pattern ALPHA = Pattern.compile("\\p{Alpha}+");
```

```
Map<String, String> colorsByKey = // initializing the map
    
String[] result = colorsByKey.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("colors"))
    .flatMap(e -> ALPHA.matcher(e.getValue()).results())
    .map(MatchResult::group)
    .toArray(String[]::new);
```

#### Note:

As it has been said in the note to previous solution, in case if strings like `"Red, Dark Blue"` are valid, the pattern needs to be changed, a possible option would be `"[\\p{Alpha}\\p{Space}]+"` (*white spaces and alphabetic character*). And similarly, `map()` operation should be added to the pipeline:

```
.map(s -> s.replaceAll("\\s*", ""))
```

Comment: But using “non alpha” as a separator instead of comma, is a semantic change anyway. Consider for example `"Red, Dark Blue, Green"`…

Comment: @Holger Agree, it's not clear whether OP was replacing white-spaces on purpose or not. I've addressed this case in each of the solution.